# Need to replicate data from oracle 12c based on partition using Oracle golden gate Big-Data and kafka Handler

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle12c, apache-kafka-connect, oracle-golden-gate

I want to replicate data from oracle to MongoDB , My application flow goes like this

Oracle 12c (DB)-->Oracle golden gate classic--->Oracle golden gate Big-Data--->kafka system--->Consumer Application(target MongoDB)

Everything is working we are able to consume trail files and processing and storing in mongoDB.

For initial Load I want to replicate data based on oracle partitions like for below table with OCT_19 partition.

`SELECT * FROM DBUSER.XYZ partition (OCT_19) ;`

Where Do Need to change the config for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the SQLPREDICATE and FILTER options in the GoldenGate documentation for verifying if they are suitable for you.